# Unable to run OpenCV sample code on Xcode 7

Tags: ios, xcode, opencv, xcode7

I am trying to run Chapter4 and chapter15 of this book examples for OpenCV, however I am unable to run them in Xcode 7. What is the best workaround?

Here is the [github source repository](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_for_ios_book_samples) for them. Would be great if someone could get **Chapter04_DetectingFaces** to work.

[image]
Regards

Comment: Please add more concrete error messages, or, if your program is running, describe what it does and what you would expect.

Answer (score 0):

Go and download the latest framework for iOS on [OpenCV](http://opencv.org) just drag and drop it into the project and select "Copy items if needed" delete the red appearing `opencv2.framework`.
Note the `iOS.h` is now in `opencv2/imgcodecs/ios.h`